# Word for loading/unloading shipments for cargo delivery

Tags: word-request

Let's say I have a cargo company like FedEx. I have warehouses in some city, which I use to load shipments.

What is the term for those places in English? Can I use *loading location*? And what would be the term for the "unloading" location?

Comment: Are you looking for a _specialised term_, if one exists? There's not necessarily an everyday/commonsense term that means a loading/unloading location.

Answer (score 4):

The term for a warehouse where you store goods prior to shipment is "warehouse". As user73787 says, many mail-order companies these days call it a "fulfillment center".

A place where goods are loaded onto trucks to begin shipment, or where they are unloaded from trucks for customer pickup or local delivery, is called a "terminal".

A place where goods are unloaded from one truck and loaded onto others is called a "breakbulk center". (Like if a truck leaves Los Angeles with several shipments intended for places all over the east cost, it might stop in a breakbulk center in Philadelphia where the goods for Boston are then transferred to one truck, those for New York City to another, those for Baltimore to another, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Besides terms already mentioned, consider *[loading dock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loading_dock)*, which generally refers to “an area of a building where goods vehicles (usually road or rail) are loaded and unloaded” and more specifically to a raised dock at the right height for moving stuff in and out of trucks or railcars.

Another term for warehouses and distribution centers is *[godown](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/godown)*. This term is in common use in India, East Africa, Singapore, and Malaysia.